# Node.JS as a REST service and Angular.JS with socket.io

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I have a node.js server which only acts as a RESTful service. I have an angular js frontend which consumes the JSONs sent by Node server. I want to integrate socket.io into this application.

I tried https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io but get weird errors like `io` is not defined and `Unknown provider: $animateProvider`. Are there any good examples with the exact scenario?